# "to have played" or "would have played"?

Tags: infinitives, past-simple, conditionals

I have two sentences here but I'm not sure if I write them correctly. And this is my first time trying to use be to + infinitive in the sentence 2 so I'm not sure if I used it right. Please see the following:

1. "She wanted **to** thoroughly **clean up** the house in-and-out"

and

2. "We were **to have played** computer game after the lunch, and now we were sadly mopping our room."

or

3. "We **would have played** computer game originally, and now we were sadly mopping our room."

Is the grammar correct?

Answer (score 1):

In sentence 1:
`She wanted to thoroughly clean up the house in-and-out.`

I think ", inside and outside", preceded by a comma,  would be more idiomatic than "in-and-out".

In sentence 2, the use of "were to have played" is correct, but it's uncommon. It might be better to use "would have".

With singular "game", you need an article: "**a** computer game". If you use the plural "computer games", you don't need the article.

In sentence 2, the conjunction "but" would fit better:
"We would have played a computer game after lunch, but now we were sadly mopping our room."

Comment: I agree that "would have played" sounds more typical of everyday English than "were to have played". Given the context, I would probably say "We were supposed to play computer games" or "We were planning to play computer games" or "We were going to play computer games".

Answer (score 0):

Remember that modal verbs ("would" in sentence 3) do not take infinitives with to.
So, it is correct to say "We would have played" "We might have played" "We should have played." If we use the present tense of these verbs, we see the same thing: "We will have played" "We should have played" "We may have played" etc.

However, with non-modal verbs we often do use the to+infinitive construction to "complete" the meaning of the verb. "She wanted *something*," the to+infinitive tells us what she wanted. This explains sentence 1 and 2.

Sentence 2 sounds formal because it is using the subjunctive; generally speaking, English speakers do not use the subjunctive.

But be careful with your tenses! In sentences 2 and 3, it should be "now we *are* sadly moping." In these sentences "now" is an adverb of time emphasizing the present and contrasting with the hypothetical actions "were to have played" and　"would have played."